# create matrix with column names and row names in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new in Python. I want to create a m x n matrix and add names to its columns and rows. I have a list contains row names and a list contains column names. It seems that I need to use "Pandas". But I do not know how to use it. Can any body help me?

Comment: Pandas has a nice 10-minute-introduction section in its documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html.  Please, read it first and if anything is still unclear add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You just read in the file with index_col=0 indicating those will be your rownames and pandas automatically gets your colnames from the first row.

```
m = pd.read_csv("mat.txt,delimiter="\t",index_col=0)
```

you can convert to a numpy matrix using

```
m.as_matrix()
```

to sparse matrix using

```
import scipy.sparse
scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(m.values)
```

Hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas DataFrame-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=row_names_list, columns=cols_names_list)
```

E.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'])
```

Output:

```
    aa  bb  cc  dd
a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
c   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```