# How to name columns and rows of a Matrix with names embeded in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to name columns and rows of a matrix with those the columns names embeded in the matrix:

Example:

```
M = ['A:1' 'B:0' 'C:0', 'A:0' 'B:1' 'C:0', 'A:0' 'B:0' 'C:1']
```

to:

```
M = ['1' 'A' 'B' 'C','2' '1' '0' '0','3' '0' '1' '0', '4' '0' '0' '1']
```

Much like Excel format where the columns are labeled by the variables embeded in the matrix, and the rows are numbered.

This code should be used later on in analysis of big data

Comment: What's `M`? A list of lists, a flat list, an array (if so, what dimension)? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

The [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library extends numpy arrays to give you a data representation (a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame)) that is closer to Excel.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 0],
                   'B': [0, 1, 0],
                   'C': [0, 0, 1]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

It also has a [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) function and [`DataFrame.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method.

To extract the underlying numpy array from a DataFrame, use the `.values` attribute:

```
print(df.values)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas DataFrame-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=row_names_list, columns=cols_names_list)
```

E.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'])
```

Output:

```
    aa  bb  cc  dd
a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
c   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: You've posted this exact same answer on another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173486/create-matrix-with-column-names-and-row-names-in-python/72286585#72286585).

Comment: Yes. I do not know how to link both. I guessed it would be better to put an answer then to leave it. Would be happy to learn if you know how to do that. Thanks